# Visual Studio 2015 NuGet Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I`m New in ASP.NET MVC, when I run my project Following error comes:

---

> The command ""E:\Projects\Latest Code(30Jun2016)\shipping\shipping
>   2\HorizenWeb\HorizenWeb\Solutions.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "E:\Projects\Latest Code(30Jun2016)\shipping\shipping
>   2\HorizenWeb\HorizenWeb\Solutions\HorizonWeb.Web.Mvc\packages.config"
>   -source "" -o "E:\Projects\Latest Code(30Jun2016)\shipping\shipping 2\HorizenWeb\HorizenWeb\Solutions..\Packages"" exited with code 1.
>   HorizonWeb.Web.Mvc

### ***

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Thanks...@Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 0):

Update your package, your project have old packages. So Right click on solution then Manage Nuget Packages for Solution.

Comment: That project written in VS 2010 and I`m running that on VS 2015.